# Caldav filter by date-range and property

Tags: xml, calendar, icalendar, caldav

I'd like to get events from calendar that are within given range **AND ALSO** match one other property, but what caldav seems to be doing is `or` between these two or completely ignoring the other one.

Example query:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
    <D:prop xmlns:D="DAV:">
        <D:getetag/>
        <C:calendar-data />
    </D:prop>
    <C:filter>
        <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
            <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
                <C:time-range start="19000323T064000Z" end="20400323T194000Z" />
                <C:prop-filter name="DESCRIPTION">
                    <C:text-match collation="i;ascii-casemap">Text to match</C:text-match>
                </C:prop-filter>
            </C:comp-filter>
        </C:comp-filter>
    </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

Unfortunately, the `prop-filter` is ignored and all events within date-range (the huge range is on purpose here) are returned. Is there any way to combine two filters ?

Answer (score 0):

How does it know which property to apply the time-range filter to?

Does the `<C:time-range>` element need to be enclosed within a `<C:prop-filter name="DTSTART">` element?

Comment: It can, but it does not need to, from RFC: "the server MUST only return the calendar object resources that, depending on the context, have a component or property whose value intersects a specified time range.". There is a whole evaluation tree in [section 9.9](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4791#section-9.9)